# Zend the difference between autoloadernamespaces[] and autoloadernamespaces

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader

When setting up a custom library in Zend Framework **what is the difference** between `autoloadernamepaces[] = "foo"` and `autoloadernamespaces.foo = "foo"`?

Answer (score 2):

What you'll get in the config in the end is basically an array. One has a numerical index while the other has the provided key

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "foo" 
// results into this
array(0 => "foo");

autoloadernamespaces.foo = "foo"
array("foo" => "foo");
```

The advantage with the latter would be that you can always address it with a name. This might be not needed with autoloader namespaces but for other configurations this could be a life saver.